# How to avoid this compiler warning to close an OutputStream when using CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, playframework, java-8

I'm using a `CompletableFuture` for an async operation to make a download of a file and to save its contents via an `OutputStream`. The code below works, but the compiler gives me a warning to either use `try-with-resources` or to close the `OutputStream` in a `finally-clause`, although it is closed after the Future completes in `whenComplete`.

**Code:**

```
final OutputStream outputStream = Files.newOutputStream(file.toPath());
final String url = "https://example.com/some-download.zip";
final CompletionStage<WSResponse> futureResponse = this.client
        .url(url)
        .setMethod("GET")
        .stream();

futureResponse.thenCompose(res -> {
    downloadTask.setTotalBytes(res);
    Source<ByteString, ?> responseBody = res.getBodyAsSource();

    Sink<ByteString, CompletionStage<akka.Done>> outputWriter =
            Sink.foreach(bytes -> {
                downloadTask.addReceivedBytes(bytes.size());
                System.out.println(downloadTask.getProgressAsString());
                outputStream.write(bytes.toArray());
            });

    return responseBody.runWith(outputWriter, this.materializer);
}).whenComplete((res, error) -> {
    try {
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

**Warning:**

[image]

**Problem:**

When I use `try-with-resources` then the program closes the `OutPutStream` before anything is written to the file, because of the async nature of `CompletableFuture` which doesn't block.

So is there a way to declare the `OutputStream` inside the `CompletionStage` and pass it down the line?

Comment: How about opening it in the `thenCompose`, and using a try/finally?

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks, but this unfortunately doesn't work because if I declare the `OutputStream` outside the `try` block, then `finally` demands it be initialized (e.g. with null) to be able to close it and if I do that then the compiler complains that it needs to be `effectively final`, because it's inside a Lambda. Using `try-with-resources` works, but this also closes the `OutputStream` before the download starts. I hope I was able to explain it somehow understandably, sorry :)

Comment: @AndyTurner Correction! You were right in your comment. See my answer below. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion of @AndyTurner in his comment was correct. I just had to tweak the code a little bit to make it work.

I didn't realize that `responseBody.runWith()` returns another `CompletionStage`, so that using `try-with-resources` or `finally` closed the `OutputStream` in the `thenComponse` block, so the returned `CompletionStage` (from `responseBody.runWith()`) couldn't write to it anymore. This caused the error. So we simply need to process `responseBody.runWith()` 'synchronously' in the same block by using `.toCompletableFuture().get()`. This is no problem, because the block itself runs in another thread, i.e. it stays asynchronous. Since we don't return anything anymore, we also need to use `thenAccept`, which takes a `Consumer` instead of `thenCompose`, which takes a `Function`.

```
final String url = "https://example.com/some-download.zip";
final CompletionStage<WSResponse> futureResponse = this.client
        .url(url)
        .setMethod("GET")
        .stream();

futureResponse
        .thenAccept(res -> {
            try (OutputStream outputStream = Files.newOutputStream(file.toPath())) {
                downloadTask.setTotalBytes(res);
                Source<ByteString, ?> responseBody = res.getBodyAsSource();

                Sink<ByteString, CompletionStage<akka.Done>> outputWriter =
                        Sink.foreach(bytes -> {
                            downloadTask.addReceivedBytes(bytes.size());
                            System.out.println(downloadTask.getProgressAsString());
                            outputStream.write(bytes.toArray());
                        });
                responseBody.runWith(outputWriter, this.materializer).toCompletableFuture().get();
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```